# Panel header size is not changing in React-Bootstrap

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to change the size of the header in the React-Bootstrap Panel in a Typescript app. I wrapped the text in `<h1>` tags, as it's mentioned in the documentation, but nothing is being changed.

I tried to add an inline style, or even a css className in which I'm trying to change the fontSize, but again there's no result.

Here's the code.

```
const title = (<h1>{Constants.gameTitle}</h1>);
<PanelGroup defaultActiveKey="1" accordion key="accordion1">
    <Panel defaultExpanded header={title} className="changeFontSize" eventKey="1" bsSize="large" bsStyle="primary">
     </Panel>
</PanelGroup>
```

Any suggestions of a possible way to do this?

Comment: I just ran across this as well. [The documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/panel/#panels-contextual) claims that you can use the `componentClass` prop, but I see no difference between setting this to `h1` or to `h3`.

Comment: Is the title rendering at all? I don't see `header` prop in `Panel` in the latest doc. Which doc are you referring to? Also `react-bootstrap` is still targeting bootstrap-3.

Comment: Can you tell us the version of `react-bootstrap` you are using?

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/L5tLot9h/

Becuase `panel-title` has a default `font-size` so you need to use `!important` for overriding the previously assigned CSS.

```
const title = (<h1 style={{fontSize: '80px !important'}}>{Constants.gameTitle}</h1>);
<PanelGroup defaultActiveKey="1" accordion key="accordion1">
    <Panel defaultExpanded header={title} className="changeFontSize" eventKey="1" bsSize="large" bsStyle="primary">
     </Panel>
</PanelGroup>
```

Why does `(h1 or h2... etc)` elements do not apply the `font-size`?

As we can see below the `h1` `font-size` it doesn't apply because of the `panel-title` it has the `font-size` property and in this case, the `panel-title` class will take the priority.

[image]

**What do you need to fix this?**

You can use the `inline-style` as I did above plus using `!important`.

**or**

Give the selector a higher specificity (adding an additional tag, id or class to the selector), or add a CSS rule with the same selector at a later point than the existing one (in a tie, the last one defined wins).

**CSS file**

```
h1.panel-title {
    font-size: 36px;
}
h2.panel-title {
    font-size: 30px;
}
h3.panel-title {
    font-size: 24px;
}
h4.panel-title {
    font-size: 18px
}
h5.panel-title {
    font-size: 14px
}
h6.panel-title {
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do that using something like below

```
var {Button, PanelGroup, Panel, ButtonGroup, DropdownButton, MenuItem} = ReactBootstrap

const titleStyle = {'fontSize': '50px'}

const title = <h1 style={titleStyle}>Tarun</h1>;

const nav = ( <PanelGroup defaultActiveKey="1" accordion key="accordion1">
    <Panel defaultExpanded header={title} className="changeFontSize" eventKey="1" bsSize="large" bsStyle="primary">
     </Panel>
</PanelGroup>);


var mountNode = document.getElementById("app")
ReactDOM.render(nav, mountNode);
```

Below is a JSFiddle for the same

http://jsfiddle.net/6u0eaqur/1/

And the result is

[image: Header with font]

**Why h1, h2, h3 has no impact on size?**

By default the React component is assigning a `panel-title` class which has a `font-size` of `16px` specified. So whichever tag you use, the `font-size` will be overridden by the class

[image: Font of panel-title]

Comment: Why is `titleStyle` required when you already have an `<h1>` tag? From what I can tell, no matter which `h` tag you use, the title is the same size by default.